# MS SQL Server two foreign keys to 1 field

Tags: database

i have 3 tables.

1. Employees
2. Contractors
3. Jobs

The picture below illustrates two possible scenarios for table design and relationships.

[image: Scenarios]

Is the first scenario possible? Like having two foreign keys each one from a different table to one ID field in jobs.

Should i use the second scenario? but then i would always have 1 null ID field in jobs, because it's either an employee or contractor who works the job.

Lastly, is there another way of doing this? A better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have just one Employee table and add another column to indicate the type of employee. i.e. do away with the Contractor table entirely. The problem then goes away too.

Comment: I would, but the thing is, it's a minimum representation of contractors table. Truth is, they both have more fields and different fields.

Comment: Well, if you can't merge them then option 2 is much the better and clearer method. Where it is an Employee Job make sure that Job.ContractorId is Null or some nonsense value like 0 or -1 and visa versa for a Contractor Job. If you go for Option 1 add a flag on the Job table to indicate what kind of entity it relates to.

Comment: I'm going to go with Option 2, your right it's a better method